Determining the "u" part of a Google Thumbnail URL
Using Google Apps Script, I generate a list of users and their photo thumbnails for a work intranet. This intranet requires logging into Google using Oauth.
The thumbnail URLs look something like:
https://lh3.google.com/ao/AHP4FtlN1wzP_pjUvk0MEP-2tSZumfJi9eMJmCvi0mK8QDvuUSyU-kzXARP_oCrxjC6ugchgVUA=s288-c
This on its own will not work and yields the following "generic" silhouette placeholder:

If I add the following "user" part to the URL: /u/1
https://lh3.google.com/u/1/ao/AHP4FtlN1wzP_pjUvk0MEP-2tSZumfJi9eMJmCvi0mK8QDvuUSyU-kzXARP_oCrxjC6ugchgVUA=s288-c
The image works and I get the correct thumbnail at the requested size (288x288 pixels )
I understand that the 1 in /u/1 denotes the order I've logged into my Google account. One means it's the second account I've logged into, 0 being the first.
I've also found that for some Google URLs, I can replace the number with the account I want to use to access the resource.
e.g.
Google Drive thumbnails:
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=lee.taylor@example.com&sz=w175&id=ALV-UjXcpIrWPSs-S6EKh2joeQh_C18zIGCcCqBt9arhmKbF1_kaZZp
Google Calendar links:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/lee.taylor@example.com/r/eventedit/1234567890
So, my question is. How can I determine the user number that my email address maps to?
I am using PHP with GoogleOAuth to login with the following code/scopes:
$this->client = new Google\Client();
$this->client->setAuthConfig($oauthCredentialsFile);
$this->client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);

$this->client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'); 
$this->client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'); 

I've checked the values of the OAuth values and $me = $oauth2Service->userinfo_v2_me->get();, but nothing helps.
Is there anything I can add to determine which user (/u/1) I am currently?
I know that for most users of the intranet they will only be logged into one Google Account and I can therefore just use /u/0, but this seems clunky.
I've also found that I can download the thumbnail photo in Google Apps Script, but this size is limited to 96x96 pixels and I could not find a way of getting a larger size.

The mention that you are using Google Apps Script to generate a list of thumbnails and the PHP code leans into chitchat... In other words, both mentions do not warrant the including [tag:google-apps-script] and tag:php] as if those mentions are removed the question still is focused on Google OAuth.

OK, I had another look at this.
This method attempts to load an image only accessible by the relevant user.
Supply this image as the baseUrl and remove any authuser elements. The code then tries to load the image using ?authuser=0 ... ?authuser=5.
It doesn't seem to work in incognito mode though.
function determineValidAuthuser()
{
    let baseUrl = "https://lh3.google.com/d/1oA508StlM2QV8EoW9Zhz9SPhRXoxscZp=s320-w320-h200-k-p";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
        var attemptLoad = function(i)
        {
            let img = new Image();
            img.onload = function()
            {
                resolve(authuser);
            }

            img.onerror = function()
            {
                if(authuser++ > 5)
                    reject();
                else
                    attemptLoad(authuser);
            }

            img.src = baseUrl + `?authuser=${i}`;
        }

        var authuser = 0;
        attemptLoad(authuser);
    });
}

determineValidAuthuser().then(function(authuser)
{
    console.log(`The authuser is ${authuser}`);
}).catch(function()
{
    console.log(`The authuser is unknown, perhaps try 0 and see what happens...`);
});


For anyone else who's been scratching their heads. I found that you can add the following to the end of the URL:
"?authuser=lee.taylor@example.com"
Thus:
https://lh3.google.com/ao/AHP4FtlN1wzP_pjUvk0MEP-2tSZumfJi9eMJmCvi0mK8QDvuUSyU-kzXARP_oCrxjC6ugchgVUA=s288-c?authuser=lee.taylor@example.com

Hope that helps someone else!
NB:
After playing around a little more, the above method with an email address is equivalent to authuser=0, so not much use really. I will leave this answer here in case it inspires any other thoughts.

When using Google OAuth, the "u" part is not needed, the critical part is the Google OAuth Token.
Regarding the URLs with the lh3.google.com domain, this URL is temporary. This means that they will stop working after a short time.
Related

How to get a link of the thumbnail of a google drive file using google apps script?
Fetching a drive file image using Urlfetch App in GAS


The Google OAuth step is before, just giving context. I'm logged in and all is ok. The problem is when a user is logged in to two or more Google accounts at the same time.

The premise of the question is wrong... I suggest looking at the link I just added to my answer, and if you still have questions, post a new question including the [mcve] that of the Google Apps Script that you are using. P.D. Instead of using Google Drive your might have to use the Google Admin SDK or the Google People API.

I already have the thumbnail link. It works fine but only if you are logged into one Google account in the browser. Otherwise their is ambiguity and this must be resolved by supplying the authuser in the url.
